# Show result of a query in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I'm very beginner and amateur in C#,
I learned how to connect and read tables in database files with `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

I connect to db with `sqlconnection` and execute commands with `sqlcommand` using `ExecuteReader` method.
Now I want to Show its results in a Microsoft ReportViewer. How I can give my query to ReportViewer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will want to fill a `DataSet` with the results of your query and then use it as a datasource for `ReportViewer`.

[How to: Fill a Dataset with Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Building Reports from a DataSet using ReportViewer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataSetReports04252007100945AM/DataSetReports.aspx)